# Understanding ManualResetEvent in asynchronous server socket

Tags: c#, asyncsocket

```
Socket SocketSrv;
public static ManualResetEvent Done = new ManualResetEvent(false);
IPEndPoint IPP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 1234);

void Listening()
{
    SocketSrv = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                           SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    try
    {
        SocketSrv.Bind(IPP);
        SocketSrv.Listen(5);

        while (true)
        {
            Done.Reset();
            info.Text = "Waiting for connections....";
            SocketSrv.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(Connection),
                                  SocketSrv);
            Done.WaitOne();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception error)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
    }
}

void Connection(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    Done.Set();
    Socket con= (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
    Socket handler = con.EndAccept(ar); 
}
```

I'm  trying to understand the `ManualResetEvent` in this asynchronus operation since I've never used it.

- Step1. The `SocketSrv` is created to accept TCP connections and the type of sending and receving "commands" is stream.
- Step2. The socket is binded with the ip,port and then we start listening for connections.
- Step3. In the while loop :

  - The `ManualResetEvent` is Reset (I understand that the `ManualResetEvent` is a class which type is Boolean and indicates whenever a thread is busy or not).In this case , the event is always reset because if there's a connection made and another one is coming I need to reset it and start the "operation" again.
  - In the `BeingAccept` I'm being starting the asynchronous operation, the callback function which is executed and the `IAsyncResult` argument which will become the "socket".
- Step4. The `ResetEvent` is now Waiting blocking the current thread and waiting for the handler in the connection method to be ended so it can finish initializing the current connection.
- Step5. In the connection thread the `ResetEvent` sets the signal true which means... well I don't know what does it means. I think it tells to the `ResetEvent` to unblock the main thread.

In the 'con' socket I'm getting the `AsyncState`. I have no idea what does it means.

In the handler socket I'm telling the `ResetEvent` that the connection was made.

Things being said, could someone tell me if what I've said is true/wrong and why?

Comment: It is quite pointless.  Just use the non-asynchronous version, SocketSrv.Accept(), to get the exact same outcome without the event.

Comment: Not really..because I'll continue adding the reading,writing using asynchronus operations so it can accept multiple connections while doing other operations..

Comment: Nothing is "continuing" while the code is blocked on the Done.WaitOne() call.  Maybe you intended to make this asynchronous, it just isn't in its current version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event is used so that when a connection occurs `BeginAccept` won't be called again until the `Connect` method has been invoked.  e.g. `WaitOne` halts the thread until `Set` is called.  `Reset` is called to set the state of the event back to signalled so that `WaitOne` will halt the thread again so that it will wait for `Connect` to be called again.

Personally, I don't use this particular pattern.  I've never seen an explanation of the point of this pattern.  If there were some shared state between the `BeginAccept` loop and the `Connect` method, it might make sense.  But, as written no state is guarded by use of the event.  When I use `BeginAccept` I simply don't use an event, and I've used code like this to deal with many connections a second.  Use of the event *will do nothing* to prevent errors with too many connections at a time.  And quite frankly, to use an asynchronous method and force it to effectively be synchronous defeats the purpose.

The `AysncState`, from the point of view of `BeginAccept`, is simply opaque data.  It's the "state" that is used for that particular async operation.  This "state" is application-specific.  You use whatever you need when you want to process a connection asynchronously.  In the case of the `BeginAccept` callback, you usually want to do something with the server socket and it's passed in for the state so you have access to it to call `EndAccept`.  Since `SocketSrv` is a member field, you don't really *need* to do this, you could do this instead:

```
SocketSrv.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(Connection), null);
//...
void Connection(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    Socket handler = SocketSrv.EndAccept(ar); 
    //...
}
```

Your comments seem to suggest you have a good grasp of this particular bit of code.  Your "Step4" is a bit off, it's not waiting for the `Connection` method to end, just for it to *start* (since `Set` is called as the first line).  And yes, "Step5", the `Set` means it unblocks the `WaitOne` so the main thread call call `Reset` then `BeginAccept`.